# Setting up django with docker on VM

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker. I'm trying to set up django with docker by following this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

I'm on Windows 10 Home running Docker with DockerToolbox (using a VM).

My problem is when I run 
docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample . I can't see the Django files created, even though the docker image has been successfully built.

PS:

• When I check the container in Kitematic, the path is /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

• When I go to the Volumes tab, the local folder is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose` is used to build and configure containers [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/). You dont necessarily need to use it, but when creating complex docker environments it makes it easier.

It sounds like you want to create the container then create your django project. A better approach is to initialize the project first, then use the Dockerfile to copy the project files to the conatiner.

If you want to create the container and then create a django project inside it, you need to use `docker` cli tool to execute commands inside your container:

Steps:

1. Build your container `docker-compose up --build`
2. List your containers `docker ps` and get the name or hash
3. Run commands in the container `docker exec -it [CONTAINER] django-admin startproject composeexample`

`docker exec -it [CONTAINER]` command can be used to run any kind of command on the docker container.